# Get value from csv file depending on 10 values JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, csv, return-value

I have a csv file, with 10 variables that all can be in (0,1). The eleventh variable contains a output value. 
How can I display a field with the outcome variable, depending on the values of the first 10 variables in Javascript? (the .csv file is uploaded to a server)? 
So in sum there are 10^2 combinations and I don't want to use if else functions.

Example: 
first line

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1.5
```

second line

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 2.5
```

Now if the values of the first 10 are matched, then the value of 1.5 should be put out.

How can I do this with Javascript? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So basically you want to use a CSV as kind of a lookup-table? Btw it is 2^10 combinations an d not 10^2 - slightly more ,-)

Comment: Sirko, sorry, that's right :) Yes a look up table, uploading it, people can fill out a questionnaire, the answers are coded 1/0 and should then be provided with an outcome for their answer. The description of me was a bit, I am sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zXHNZ/1/):

```
var data = [
    "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1.5",
    "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0, 2.5"
    ];

var handlers = {
    "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1": function(value){
        console.log("I am handler 1, value is: " + value);
    },
    "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0": function(value){
        console.log("I am handler 2, value is: " + value);
    }    
}

var execute = function(record){
    var lastCommaIndex = record.lastIndexOf(",");
    var firstSection = record.substring(0, lastCommaIndex);
    var dataSection = record.substring(lastCommaIndex + 1);   
    handlers[firstSection](dataSection);
}

for (var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
    execute(data[i]);
}
```

Also, you might want to get rid of the commas between the binary digits, to save bandwidth.
This can also be generalized to classes of 01010.., if you want to make a common handler for some of the combinations.